# Python Pandas - Error pivoting table with mixed value types

Tags: python

I am trying to pivot on the following table [the result of pd.concat(x)], with this line of code:

```
df = pd.concat(x).pivot_table(index=["SECURITY", "DATE"], columns="variable", values="value")

          DATE     SECURITY        value           variable
0   2017-02-01  EDH8 COMDTY       98.365            PX_LAST
1   2017-02-02  EDH8 COMDTY        98.37            PX_LAST
2   2017-02-03  EDH8 COMDTY        98.36            PX_LAST
3   2017-02-06  EDH8 COMDTY       98.405            PX_LAST
4   2017-02-07  EDH8 COMDTY        98.41            PX_LAST
5   2017-02-08  EDH8 COMDTY       98.435            PX_LAST
6   2017-02-09  EDH8 COMDTY       98.395            PX_LAST
0   2017-02-01  EDH8 COMDTY  1.00804e+06           OPEN_INT
1   2017-02-02  EDH8 COMDTY  1.00999e+06           OPEN_INT
2   2017-02-03  EDH8 COMDTY  1.01918e+06           OPEN_INT
3   2017-02-06  EDH8 COMDTY  1.02386e+06           OPEN_INT
4   2017-02-07  EDH8 COMDTY  1.02461e+06           OPEN_INT
5   2017-02-08  EDH8 COMDTY  1.04626e+06           OPEN_INT
6   2017-02-09  EDH8 COMDTY  1.05029e+06           OPEN_INT
0   2017-02-01  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
1   2017-02-02  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
2   2017-02-03  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
3   2017-02-06  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
4   2017-02-07  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
5   2017-02-08  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
6   2017-02-09  EDH8 COMDTY   2018-03-19  LAST_TRADEABLE_DT
```

This results in the following error though:  DataError: No numeric types to aggregate.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just choose a different, almost arbitrary, aggfunc; you're only ever going to have one element to operate on.  For example, `sum`:

```
In [37]: df.pivot_table(index=["SECURITY", "DATE"], 
                        columns="variable", values="value", 
                        aggfunc=sum)
Out[37]: 
variable               LAST_TRADEABLE_DT     OPEN_INT PX_LAST
SECURITY    DATE                                             
EDH8 COMDTY 2017-02-01        2018-03-19  1.00804e+06  98.365
            2017-02-02        2018-03-19  1.00999e+06   98.37
            2017-02-03        2018-03-19  1.01918e+06   98.36
            2017-02-06        2018-03-19  1.02386e+06  98.405
            2017-02-07        2018-03-19  1.02461e+06   98.41
            2017-02-08        2018-03-19  1.04626e+06  98.435
            2017-02-09        2018-03-19  1.05029e+06  98.395
```

Or `min`, or `max`, etc.  Note that if you're mixing non-numerical and numerical columns, your `value` column is going to be of `dtype=object`, and so you're going to want to re-numerify (?) the resulting columns to make sure they're appropriately dtyped.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if the data type for `value` column is numeric types, otherwise (for example string/date) it may cause problem for the default aggregate function. In that case, you may want to use another `aggfunc` explicitly, such as storing them into an array.

According to the [official document](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), `values : column to aggregate, optional`, `aggfunc : function or list of functions, default numpy.mean`.